# How do I integrate two 1-D data arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, integration, interpolation

I have two tabulated data arrays, x and y, and I don't know the function that generated the data. I want to be able to evaluate the integral of the line produced by the data at any point along the x-axis.

Rather than interpolating a piecewise function to the data and then attempting to integrate that, which I am having trouble with, is there something I can use that will simply provide the integral by evaluating the arrays?

When searching for solutions, I have seen references to iPython and Pandas, but I haven't been able to find the parts of those packages that will aid in this task.

If there isn't a way to simply integrate the arrays, could you provide some advice on the best way to handle this task?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Scipy has some nice tools to perform numerical integration.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html)

For example, you can use [`scipy.integrate.simpson`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simpson.html) to perform simpson's Rule, and you can pass it the following:

> scipy.integrate.simps(y, x=None, dx=1, axis=-1, even='avg')

> Parameters :
> y : array_like
> Array to be integrated.

> x : array_like, optional
> If given, the points at which y is sampled.

> dx : int, optional
> Spacing of integration points along axis of y. Only used when x is None. Default is 1.

> axis : int, optional
> Axis along which to integrate. Default is the last axis.

> even : {‘avg’, ‘first’, ‘str’}, optional

> ‘avg’ : Average two results:1) use the first N-2 intervals with
> a trapezoidal rule on the last interval and 2) use the last N-2 intervals with a trapezoidal rule on the first interval.

> ‘first’ : Use Simpson’s rule for the first N-2 intervals with
> a trapezoidal rule on the last interval.

> ‘last’ : Use Simpson’s rule for the last N-2 intervals with a
> trapezoidal rule on the first interval.

So you can use your two arrays to do numerical integration.

Comment: What if you were dealing with multiple arrays/lists? How can you perform integration?

Comment: You make my day, thank you a lot... it is working like magic and save a lot of time

Answer (score 18):

Scipy has an [integration](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html) feature that can help you.

If you want to use the [cumulative sum of trapezoids](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html) for integration, which would probably be best for a series of points.

You can do this:

```
>>> from scipy import integrate
>>> x = np.linspace(-2, 2, num=20)
>>> y = x
>>> y_int = integrate.cumtrapz(y, x, initial=0)
>>> plt.plot(x, y_int, 'ro', x, y[0] + 0.5 * x**2, 'b-')
>>> plt.show()
```

This will also plot the data and show it to you graphically.  This is the integration call `integrate.cumtrapz(y, x, initial=0)` where x, and y are your two arrays.

Comment: can not edit your post. the actual correct link to cumulative sum of trapezoids would be here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html