# How can I calculate Area Under the Curve (AUC) and incremental area under the curve (iAUC) for some values taken over a time period in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some values for different variables (A, B, C) taken over time (baseline, 15 mins later later, 45 mins later) for participants (AA, BB, CC, DD).

How using the trapezoid rule can I calculate the area under the curve AUC and iAUC for these variables A, B, C by time mins in python for each participant?

Example Data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD'],
                    'Time (mins)': [0, 15, 45, 0, 15, 45, 0, 15, 45, 0, 15, 45],
                    'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6],
                    'B': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6],
                    'C': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6],       
                    })
```

Unsure how to begin, most examples found detail **ROC curve** examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I integrate two 1-D data arrays in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602076/how-do-i-integrate-two-1-d-data-arrays-in-python)

Comment: That answer doesn't from what I can see show how to calculate the iAUC

Comment: You cannot calculate AUC for a dataset. AUC is a measurement of how good a *classifier* is. In order to create a classifier from a dataset, you must make choices about what the independent variables are, what the dependent variable is, and what classification model to use. Those aren't choices we can make for you, so this question is not answerable.

Comment: Re-worded the question, many thanks

Comment: @CB_datarookie I see - I misunderstood the question. I thought you meant AUC [as that term is used in statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve).

Comment: @CB_datarookie Ok, I guess I misunderstood. I thought you were asking about estimating the area under a curve using the [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). One of the answers that I linked shows how to do that using scipy